# angular handsontable not working with regular scope variable

Tags: angularjs, handsontable

I have and angular `scope` variable called `xd` which i am trying to display in a table. When i use a regular table, it works fine:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr ng-repeat="x in xd">
    <th ng-bind="x.title"/>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now i am trying to use [ngHandsonTable](https://github.com/handsontable/ngHandsontable) for the same purpose. As the documentation is still not proper, i tried something like this but somehow it is not showing anything. How do i use it to function properly?

```
<hot-table id="previewTable" columnHeaders="false" settings="htSettings" datarows="xd" >
</hot-table>
```

sample dataset of xd:

```
[
  {
    "title": "mytitle1"
  }
  {
    "title": "mytitle2"
  }
  {
    "title": "mytitle3"
  }
]
```

Another output of xd:

```
[
  {
    "primary": "2",
    "title": "mytitle1"
  }
  {
    "primary": "3",
    "title": "mytitle2"
  }
  {
    "primary": "4",
    "title": "mytitle3"
  }
]
```

I would like to dynamically assign these column headers and values in the `<hot-table>`

Comment: You also need to define the columns (`hot-column`) as mentioned in the docs at [handsontable/ngHandsontable#usage](https://github.com/handsontable/ngHandsontable#usage).

Comment: hi.thank you for the response. It works with the hot column. But is there a way to dynamically set the rowdata? Because my json can differ in its structure according to some queries i make.

Comment: Can you provide sample dataset of `xd`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fiddling around with this, I came up with:

HTML table:

```
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="demoCtrl">
  <hot-table
    id="demoTable"
    datarows="xd"
    settings="{
      colHeaders: xdColumns
    }">
  </hot-table>
</div>
```

Where the columns are the attribute names:

```
$scope.xdColumns = Object.keys($scope.xd[0]);
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hysx1g10/4/

Since your data looks kind of confusing (every item has a `title` attribute), I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for. But as in a regular table you got one member (of the `xd` array) per row.